# How to convert canvas animations from vanilla js into a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am struggling to convert a canvas animation from vanilla js to react component. I tried to export the js from a separate file. But it did not work. Futerh=more I tried to use useref and use state as advised from a medium article

[The link is:](https://medium.com/@ruse.marshall/converting-a-vanilla-js-canvas-animation-to-react-78443bad6d7b)
Here is the code:

```
let canvas, ctx, w, h, snows, snows2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    resizeReset();
    animationLoop();
}

function resizeReset() {
    w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    snows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        snows.push(new Snow());
    }
    snows2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        snows2.push(new Snow2());
    }
}

function animationLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    drawScene();
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}

function drawScene() {
    for (let i = 0; i < snows.length; i++) {
        snows[i].update();
        snows[i].draw();
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < snows2.length; i++) {
        snows2[i].update();
        snows2[i].draw();
    }
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

class Snow {
    constructor() {
        this.reset();
        this.rgb = "219,172,52";
    }
    reset() {
        this.x = getRandomInt(0, w);
        this.xc = ((this.x - (w / 2)) / (w / 2)) / 2;
        this.y = getRandomInt(-(h * 0.3), h);
        this.yc = getRandomInt(10, 15) / 10;
        this.size = getRandomInt(10, 20) / 10;
        this.a = getRandomInt(-10, 0) / 10;
        this.ac = getRandomInt(3, 5) / 100;
    }
    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${this.rgb}, ${this.a})`;
        ctx.strokeStyle = `rgba(${this.rgb}, ${this.a})`;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    update() {
        this.x += this.xc;
        this.y += this.yc;
        this.a += this.ac;
        if (this.a > 2) {
            this.ac *= -1;
        } else if (this.a < 0 && this.ac < 0) {
            this.reset();
        }
    }
}

class Snow2 {
    constructor() {
        this.reset();
        this.rgb = "256,256,256";
    }
    reset() {
        this.x = getRandomInt(0, w);
        this.y = getRandomInt(0, h);
        this.size = getRandomInt(0, 5) / 10;
        this.a = getRandomInt(-10, 0) / 10;
        this.ac = 0.01;
    }
    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${this.rgb}, ${this.a})`;
        ctx.strokeStyle = `rgba(${this.rgb}, ${this.a})`;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    update() {
        this.y -= 0.1;
        this.a += this.ac;
        if (this.a > 1.5) {
            this.ac *= -1;
        } else if (this.a < 0 && this.ac < 0) {
            this.reset();
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeReset);re
```

I will be really thankful to anyone who can help me. Please

I tried to put it in a separate file and tried to export. I tried to dabble with useref and usestate but could not make out